# Jquery fadein one div and fadeout the displayed div

Tags: jquery, html

I have 4 divs and a navbar at the top of the page.  I want to click on a link at the top and have it make the current div disappear (fade) into the new div to create a transition effect without having to scroll on my page.

Navbar code looks like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" id="home" href="#">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="portfolio" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="about" href="#">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="contact" href="#">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The divs look like this:

```
<div id="portfolio-container" class="contain">
<h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>
```

```
<div id="about-container" class="contain">
<h1>ABOUT</h1>
```

```
<div id="contact-container" class="contain">
<h1>CONTACT</h1>
```

I've been trying the following incomplete jquery snippet but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#portfolio-container').hide();
    $('#contact-container').hide();
    $('#about-container').hide();

    $('#portfolio').click(function ()
    {
        if ($('.contain').is(":visible")){
            $('.contain').hide();
        }

        $('#portfolio-container').show();
        $('#portfolio-container').fadeIn();
    });

    $('#about').click(function ()
    {
        if ($('.contain').is(":visible")){
            $('.contain').hide();
        }

        $('#about-container').show();
        $('#about-container').fadeIn();
    })
});
```

PLEASE HELP ME!

Comment: Which part isn't working ? the `.contain` hide or the other `div` fadein ?

Comment: I know terrible title and I only have 3 divs displayed.  One had personal info but you guys should get the point anyways

Comment: When I click on portfolio the first div fades and portfolio comes in right, when I click back to another div, portfolio fades and the other div never comes back.  So I think the div fadein @MojoAllmighty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandy try this one. i hope you helpfull this
 [jsfindle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/zk95xpje/1/)

html code like this

```
<div class="container">
     <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" id="home" href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="portfolio" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="about" href="#">ABOUT</a>
        </li>

        </ul>
</div> 
    <div class="page-body">
    <div id="portfolio-container" class="contain-show">
        <h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>       
    </div>

    <div id="about-container" class="contain-hide">
        <h1>ABOUT</h1> 
    </div>

    </div>    
</div>
```

java script code like this

```
$(document).ready(function (){   
    $('#portfolio').click(function ()
    {  
        $( ".contain-show" ).fadeOut( "slow", function(e) {       
                $(this).removeClass('contain-show').addClass('contain-hide');          
            $( "#portfolio-container" ).fadeIn( "slow", function(e) {
                $(this).removeClass('contain-show').addClass('contain-show');          
            });
        });          
    });

    $('#about').click(function ()
    {        
       $( ".contain-show" ).fadeOut( "slow", function(e) {
          $(this).removeClass('contain-show').addClass('contain-hide');          
          $( "#about-container" ).fadeIn( "slow", function(e) {
               $(this).removeClass('contain-show').addClass('contain-show');          
          });   
       });    
    });
});
```

css like this

```
#portfolio-container{
  background-color:green;
}

#about-container{
  background-color:red;
}

.collapse {
      display: block; 
}

.container{
  background-color:#92c7ff;
}

#navbar{
 background-color: #e7e7e7
}
.contain-show{
   display: block;
}

.contain-hide{
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All i did was to close `.contain` div for PORTOFOLIO and ABOUT and they seem to work. JSFiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/k96dLrbu/

```
<div id="portfolio-container" class="contain">
   <h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>
</div>
<div id="about-container" class="contain">
   <h1>ABOUT</h1>
</div>
```